# Why I receive error 10001 when Parsing JSON to Excel

Tags: arrays, json, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a code that gets updated stock prices by parsing JSON. I basically did the following:
1 -  Downloaded VBA JSON latest version.
2 - Extracted it, open VBA code editor in excel (Alt + F11) and imported the 
    library.
3 - Add a reference to Microsoft scripting runtime. (Tools > references > 
    select)

For some reason I keep getting the error below:

> Err.Raise 10001, “JSONConverter”, json_ParseErrorMessage(JsonString,
>   json_Index, “Expecting ‘{‘ or ‘[‘”)

```
Sub getData()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim symbol As Variant
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim myrequest As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Activate

    'Last row find
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ws.Range("A4:A" & lastrow)

    'Clear Prior Prices
    ws.Range("B4:B" & lastrow).ClearContents

    n = 4
    'Get Symbols list
    For Each symbol In rng

        Set myrequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        myrequest.Open "Get", "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" & symbol &
        "/quote"
        'myrequest.Open "Get", "https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-
        series/price/" & symbol & "%3AUS?timeFrame=1_DAY"
        myrequest.Send

        Debug.Print myrequest.ResponseText

        Dim Json As Object
        Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(myrequest.ResponseText)
        MsgBox (myrequest.ResponseText)
        i = Json(1)("latestPrice")
        ws.Range(Cells(n, 2), Cells(n, 2)) = i
        n = n + 1

    Next symbol

    ws.Columns("B").AutoFit
    MsgBox ("Data is downloaded.")

    ws.Range("B4:B" & lastrow).HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    ws.Range("B4:B" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is an example of the responsetext?

Comment: You have a list of stock symbols starting Range "a4" and below. The code will retrieve the "LastPrice" of the stock and pastes it starting cell "b4" and below.

Comment: I understand what the code does, but you need to provide the JSON string on which it is failing.  most likely the problem is with the text string and not the code.

Comment: Hi - If I understand you correctly you need the JsonCoverter code in the moduel?
It s so big It not letting me paste it. I have to go to each line of code and put 4 spaces.

Comment: no I need the output: `myrequest.ResponseText`  What is that?  What is the JSON string you are trying to parse?  According to the message it is missing something.  That is the problem.  Not the code.  What you are trying to parse is not valid.

Comment: This is a code taken from link below:

https://programmingforfinance.com/2018/02/getting-updated-stock-quotes-into-excel/

This would be an example:

https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/AAPL%3AUS?timeFrame=1

Comment: Add `Debug.Print myrequest.ResponseText` before you try parsing the response, and check the output is what you expect: seems likely your request is not returning JSON

Comment: If I try that I get "We've detected unusual activity from your computer network.  To continue, please click the box below to let us know you're not a robot."  So that seems like your problem.

Comment: Yes it seems you are right. I ca read in the immediate window:
<h2 class="main__heading">We've detected unusual activity from your computer network</h2>
       ......
 <p class="info__text">Please make sure your browser supports JavaScript and cookies and that you are not blocking them from loading. For more information you can review our <a class="info__link" href="/notices/tos">Terms of Service</a> and <a class="info__link" href="/notices/tos">Cookie Policy</a>.</p>
        </section>
What do you suggest next?

Comment: I am using Windows, but the Jsonconvertercode has references to Mac. Not sure if this is a problem too.
I added the reference "Microsoft Scripting Runtime". I still have the error

Comment: Sorry - if the owners of the site don't want you to do this, then it seems like we should respect their wishes...

Comment: You mean Bloomberg? But if you see the demo of the code, it works perfectly:

https://programmingforfinance.com/2018/02/getting-updated-stock-quotes-into-excel/

So maybe I should extract the stock price from Yahoo Finance instead maybe?

Comment: Good day - I changed the website and now I am getting an output. Can you please check the code again and tell me what I need to change to extract the latest price? Code is now returning an error at: i = Json(1)("latestPrice")

Comment: @TimWilliams Can you take a look please? Now I just need the correct format to extract the value I need....Thank You,

Comment: `i = JSON("latestPrice")`

Comment: It worked - Thank you very much :)

Comment: Hello - How can I extract the "Close" price on a specific date?
This is an example:
https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/AAPL/chart/1m?token=pk_98e61bb72fd84b7d8b5f19c579fd0d9d

Comment: @TimWilliams Helllo - It would be great if you can assist with my question above.

Comment: You'd need to loop over the collection of objects and check the date for each, then get the "close" value for the match.  This really needs to be a new question though.

Comment: @TimWilliams You are right, I will post another question.

Comment: @TimWilliams https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640259/parsing-json-to-excel-loop